# Seven letters are selected from a bag w/o replacement. What's the probability the selection contains the letters "MAT" in any order?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, multinomial-theorem

Seven letters are selected without replacement from a bag containing 9 As, 2 Ms, 6 Ts, and 81 other letters. Each of the $98 \choose 7$ selections are equally likely. What is the probability that the selection contains the letters "MAT" in any order?

---

Right off the bat, I thought it would be like choosing 1 of each desired letter, multiplied by the remaining letters in the bag that are none of the above:

$$\frac{(9)(2)(6)(81)(80)(79)(78)}{98 \choose 7}$$
Is this correct or am I missing something?

Also, is there a way to solve this using the Multinomial Theorem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since seven letters are selected, it is possible for M, A, and/or T to be selected more than once.  You could use the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle to eliminate those selections that do not contain an M, an A, and a T.

Comment: It’s not clear to me if the “MAT” can have other letters in between. Is any selection that contains at least one of each of those three letters valid, or must “MAT” occur consecutively in some order?

Comment: I think it would be: $\frac{(9)(2)(6)(95)(94)(93)(92)}{98 \choose 7}$. So, after you are "done" picking what you need (one of the 9 A's, one of the 2 M's, and one of 6 T's), you can then choose any four from the remaining 95 letters however you like.

Comment: The wording is unfortunate.  We are told that there are $\binom{98}{7}$ selections, which means the order of selection does not matter.  Therefore, the question should ask for the probability that all of the letters M, A, T are included in the selection.  There should not be a reference to the order of selection, which is misleading.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine that the letters are written on tiles, as in the game Scrabble.  Then we are selecting seven of the $98$ tiles in the bag.  We are also told that each of the 
$$\binom{98}{7}$$
selections are equally likely. Notice that those $\binom{98}{7}$ selections are not ordered.  Therefore, the number of favorable cases must not be ordered.  Consequently, we wish to answer the following question:

> What is the probability that when seven letters are selected without replacement from a bag containing nine A's, six T's, two M's, and $81$ other letters that the selection contains at least one A, at least one M, and at least one T?

We can find the number of favorable cases by subtracting the number of selections in which there are no A's or no M's or no T's from the total number of selections.

Let $S_A$, $S_M$, and $S_T$ denote the set of selections of seven tiles that include, respectively, no A's, no M's, and no T's.  Then the unfavorable selections are those in $S_A \cup S_M \cup S_T$.  By the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), the number of unfavorable selections is 
$$|S_A \cup S_M \cup S_T| = |S_A| + |S_M| + |S_T| - |S_A \cap S_M| - |S_A \cap S_T| - |S_M \cap S_T| + |S_A \cap S_M \cap S_T|$$

$|S_A|$:  Since there are nine tiles that display an A, $98 - 9 = 89$ tiles do not display an A.  Thus, there are 
$$\binom{89}{7}$$
ways to select seven tiles that do not include an A.

$|S_M|$:  Since there are two tiles that display an M, $98 - 2 = 96$ tiles do not display an M.  Thus, there are
$$\binom{96}{7}$$
ways to select seven tiles that do not include an M.

$|S_T|$:  Since there are six tiles that display an M, $98 - 6 = 92$ tiles do not display a T.  Thus, there are
$$\binom{92}{7}$$
ways to select seven tiles that do not include a T.

$|S_A \cap S_M|$:  Since there are nine tiles that display an A and two tiles that display an M, there are $98 - 9 - 2 = 87$ tiles that display neither an A nor a T.  Thus, there are
$$\binom{87}{7}$$
ways to select seven tiles that include neither an A nor an M.

$|S_A \cap S_T|$:  Since there are nine tiles that display an A and six tiles that display a T, there are $98 - 9 - 6 = 83$ tiles that display neither an A nor a T.  Thus, there are
$$\binom{83}{7}$$
ways to select seven tiles that include neither an A nor a T.

$|S_M \cap S_T|$:  Since there are two tiles that display an M and six tiles that display a T, there are $98 - 2 - 6 = 90$ tiles that display neither an M nor a T.  Thus, there are
$$\binom{90}{7}$$
ways to select seven tiles that include neither an M nor a T.

$|S_A \cap S_M \cap S_T|$:  Since there are nine tiles that display an A, two tiles that display an M, and six tiles that display a T, there are $98 - 9 - 2 - 6 = 81$ tiles that display none of those letters.  Thus, there are
$$\binom{81}{7}$$
ways to select seven tiles that include neither an A, nor an M, nor a T.

Hence, the number of unfavorable cases is
$$\binom{89}{7} + \binom{96}{7} + \binom{92}{7} - \binom{87}{7} - \binom{83}{7} - \binom{90}{7} + \binom{81}{7}$$
Therefore, the number of favorable cases is
$$\binom{98}{7} - \binom{89}{7} - \binom{96}{7} - \binom{92}{7} + \binom{87}{7} + \binom{83}{7} + \binom{90}{7} - \binom{81}{7}$$
Dividing that number by 
$$\binom{98}{7}$$ 
yields the probability that a selection of seven tiles from the bag includes at least one A, at least one M, and at least one T.